# Deleting a file located in root directory with FtpWebRequest method

Tags: vb.net, ftpwebrequest

I'm facing a problem while implementing some FTP operation in a small tool (windows form) for data management on several FTP servers. Basically I need to connect to a list of ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx servers with credentials, look for any *.csv file available, download it to local hard disk and then delete it on ftp server.

I did most of the job like following:

- Created a loop for connecting on all ftp server in the list
- For each connection, get the file list, download each file of the list and delete it from the server

My problem is that the Delete Sub I created give me a 550 exception (not regular file). Looking deep it seems that is try to delete "/filename.csv" instead of "filename.csv", so that is the reason for the error.

I think this is related to the fact that the file is in the root directory and the URI that I pass as argument for the ftpwebrequest is in the form of "ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/filename.csv", but I don't know other ways to get around this.

Can anybody give me a tip?
Thanks

EDIT: I'm thinking that maybe sending a "cd /" command before requesting the delete could solve the situation, but I don't know how to implement it inside the FTP_Delete function. Any ideas? Thanks

```
Sub FTP_Delete(filename As String, ftp_adress As String, user As String, password As String)

    FileFullPath = ftp_adress & "/" & filename

    'Create Request To Delete File'
    Dim wrDelete As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(FileFullPath), FtpWebRequest)

    'Specify That You Want To Delete A File'
    wrDelete.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile

    'Specify Username & Password'
    wrDelete.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(user, password)

    'Response Object'
    Dim rDeleteResponse As FtpWebResponse

    Try
        rDeleteResponse = CType(wrDelete.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)  ' ** Eccezione
    Catch errore As WebException
        rDeleteResponse = DirectCast(errore.Response, FtpWebResponse)
        Me.UpdateHistory("Delete Error: " & rDeleteResponse.StatusCode & "-" & rDeleteResponse.StatusDescription)
    End Try

    'Close'
    rDeleteResponse.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you have permission to delete it? That could cause the 550.

Comment: What's the value of `ftp_adress` and `filename`? Are you sure that concatenating the two variable doesn't produce "...xxx//filename.csv" instead? Anyways, if you only receive this error with the root files, it's probably a permission issue as Jim stated.

Comment: The uri is built correctly, I've double checked it. Also about permission is ok, I've done same operation via ftp.exe tool.
The strange thing I see is the following: from cmd prompt command if I send the delete command the first time I get the following string answer

error 550 - "/filename.csv" is not regular file.

Then if I repeat the same command a second time it get deleted, so it seems not to be a permission issue.

I'm really confused, do you have any suggestion regarding my FTP_Delete function? Maybe implementing a sort of  "cd /" befor sending the ftpwebrequest would help,how?